# bring tiles besides in html

Tags: html, css

I need to get tiles beside but now whenever i add new one it comes under the old one. 
this is my codes

```
<div class="tiles">
          <div id="metro-array">
              <a class="metro-tile" style="cursor: pointer; width: 110px; height: 110px; margin:10px; display: block; background-color: deepSkyBlue;  color: #fff;">
                Name
                Age
              </a>
              <a class="metro-tile" style="cursor: pointer; width: 110px; height: 110px; margin:10px; display: block; background-color: deepSkyBlue;  color: #fff;">
               name2
               Age 2
              </a>         
    </div>
    <script src="js/tileJs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </div>
```

my css

```
 .tiles {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family:'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: lighter;
 }



 #metro-array a,  #downloads a {
    text-indent: 5px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

i tried to add margin-left manually . it works , but i will add tiles dynamically so manually adding it is not possible. and please tell me what should i change in my css?

what i'm expecting

[image]

what i'm getting

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
float:left
```

to your CSS `#metro-array a`

Here is the demo : [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrtn6xfe/)

Answer (score 1):

add float:left to #metro-array a

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left` to `#metro-array a`

Try this,

```
 #metro-array a,  #downloads a {
   text-indent: 5px;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   float:left;
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/La2g1md6/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.  #metro-array a{float:left;}